# C++ class design with shared pointers methods

Tags: c++, class-design, smart-pointer

I dont exactly know, how to handle the problem, where one class uses shared pointers but I want to call its method from inside other class via this pointer.

```
class Bar {
public:
   Bar() = default;
   ~Bar() = default;

   void OnChange(std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo) { ... }
}


class Foo {
public:
   Foo(std::shared_ptr<Bar> bar) : bar(bar) {};
   ~Foo() = default;

   void Run() { 
      bar->OnChange(this); // <=== this wont work 
   }

private:
   std::shared_ptr<Bar> bar;
}
```

How can I create "clean" design so that `Foo` can cann `OnChange` form `Bar`?

- Should I use `std::enable_shared_from_this` for `Foo`?
- Should I add `OnChange(Foo* foo)` to `Bar`?
- Some other solution?

Comment: `shared_ptr` is probably the wrong tool for your purpose. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826541/passing-shared-pointers-as-arguments

Comment: Why does `OnChange` need to share ownership?  Is there a good reason it can't be passed a reference instead?

Comment: ... yep, wh not design this as `Bar::OnChange(const Foo &foo)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in your design is that `shared_ptr` is meant to manage memory allocation and destruction of objects if they are no longer used. There is  no guarantee in your design that the `foo` object was allocated dynamically, i.e. that a `shared_ptr` could be made with `this` .

For this design to work you must let `Foo` inherit from [`enable_shared_from_this<Foo>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) and return [`shared_from_this()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this). The [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) has an example for using it.  But it's a little bit tricky.  So here a nice step-by-step explanation about how to use it and the pitfalls to avoid: [article](https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/01/11/stdshared_ptr-and-shared_from_this/)

***Additional thoughts:** The option of using an `OnChange(Foo* foo)` looks easier but it might weaken your overall design: you might have to repeat yourself as both `OnChange()` would have to stay aligned. And you'd risk dangling pointers since `OnChange()` could store a copy of its parameter in a non local place, defeating in some subtle cases the reference counting.*

Comment: `enable_shared_from_this<Foo>` - first time I saw this, this really twists my brain. I think the C++ architecture astronautes have stroke again. Actually, in the case of the OP, I would really prefer to use  `OnChange(const Foo& foo)` instead.

Comment: @DocBrown yes, C++ folks love the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) like   [Romanseco broccoli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanesco_broccoli) IRL ;-)  The reference approach that you propose is a nice alternative to the pointer version.  But  `OnChange()` could still use a `&` to transform the `const Foo&` into a `const Foo*` and store that pointer somewhere and defeat reference counting. So it all depends on the purpose of `OnChange()` and its contract.

Comment: ... reading the linked article, I think the people who invented this piled another overly complex solution on an already complex, error-prone solution to solve a problem which they would  not have without the latter (and yes, I know I am exaggerating). The forgot *completely* what [Antoine de Saint Exupéry](https://quotesondesign.com/antoine-de-saint-exupery/) once wrote about design.